# Failed to Connect to AzureTable with published Power BI report

Tags: azure, configuration, powerbi, azure-table-storage

I created a Power BI report that is connected to our Azure Tables. On my Power BI Desktop, the connection works fine. When I publish to the Power BI service, it will not connect to azure tables.
[Configure MMS_API_Statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUFQx.png)
I have tried both Access Keys as well as changing the privacy level and I still get "Failed to update data source credentials: The credentials provided for the AzureTables source are invalid."

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be the following reasons for this issue:

1. When two-factor authentication is active for an account, it does not seem to work on Power BI cloud. Turning this off has fixed the issue.
2. Resetting the profile of the user we are using to connect from PowerBI

You can follow this MSFT Q&A [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/645112/unable-to-connect-to-azure-table-storage-from-powe.html) by Oury Ba-MSFT  to check if you missed any steps.

Reference - https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Failed-to-update-data-source-credentials/idi-p/135313

Comment: Thank you!  Turns out it was the two-factor authentication.  I have replaces the connection with a custom API and it is working great!